# Audio codec consuming high battery power

Tags: battery

My powertop reports this for the two audio codec components.

```
4.85 W    100.0%                      Device         Audio codec hwC0D3: Intel
4.85 W    100.0%                      Device         Audio codec hwC0D0: Realtek
```

I think 10 W for audio is too high. Can somebody please suggest me a way to reduce the power consumption?

It'd be nice if someone could educate me on this, I have an idea about codecs in general but I have no clue about their internals? Why is it that these two components keep running always even when I am not listening to audio?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a know bug as explained in:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/877560

Here you have a few workarounds (cited from the bug comments):

#### 1. Manually force power save for the audio codec

Before proceeding, in a terminal launch the following:

```
cat /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save*
```

if the result is different from:

```
1
Y
```

then try the following commands

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save
echo Y | sudo tee /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save_controller
pkill pulseaudio
```

and then log out and log in again to get *pulseaudio* restarted.

#### 2. Let the silence fall

If you mute your **mic** and your **speakers**, the device will be deactivate. It sounds strange, but it actually works for me.

#### 3. Wait for Raring

According to the bug report, the problem is gone with kernel 3.7, and Raring will probably mount kernel 3.8.

Comment: setting `power_save` to 1 worked for me on 16.04. Thanks! (Didn't even need to `pkill pulseaudio`)